# What's the different between Console.Write("H") and Console.Write('H') in C#

Tags: c#, console

What's the different between Console.Write("H") and Console.Write('H') in C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One uses a `string` overload (the string `"H"`), one uses a `char` overload (the char `'H'`). Both output the character `H` to the stream defined in `Console.Out` without adding a newline.

Answer (score 2):

'H' is a single character (`char`) whereas "H" can have more than one character (`string`).

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in the first call, you're passing a `string` and in the second call, you're passing a `char`. Practically speaking, those two calls are equivalent.